# SOA Automation using javaScript to get the value from json using cucumber feature file

Tags: javascript

```
getScheduleInfo.inputData.newSchedules[0].name=propValues[0]; 
getScheduleInfo.inputData.newSchedules[0].description=propValues[1]; 
getScheduleInfo.inputData.newSchedules[0].startDate=propValues[2]
```

This is the javaScript function written earlier which hard coded I want to get the values dynamically using for loop

Comment: can you show your `propValues` array?

Comment: newSchedule[{
name:"String",
description:"String",
startDate:"Date",
finishDate:"Date"
]}

This is our json at the 0th Index we will get value

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array of property names (`name`, `description` and `startDate`) and access those within your `for` loop to change each property (by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)) upon each iteration like so:

```
const props = ['name', 'description', 'startDate'];
for(let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  const prop = props[i];
  getScheduleInfo.inputData.newSchedules[0][prop] = propValues[i]; 
}
```

Comment: but all values are in String I will send you pic for that